# How to verify the elements of a form in Javascript then Move to a PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to verify the inputs by javascrpit function perform() and move to a php page named i.php to save the datas in the databasse.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="i.php"  method="post">
<br>
Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
<span id="err"></span>
</br>
<br>
Password <input type="Password" name="Password" id="password">
<span id="perr"></span>
</br>
<br>
Gender 
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female">Female
</br>
<br>
Department <select name="department" id="department">
<option>------</option>
<option>ECE</option>
<option>BBA</option>
<option>ENG</option>    
</select>
</br>
<br>
<button name="btn" type="button" id="btn" onclick="perform()" >Button</button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
</br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function perform()
    {

        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var dept = document.getElementById('department').value;
        var gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
        var r =3;
        if (name.length==0) 
        {
            document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = "name not found";
            r++;
        }
        if (pass.length<=6 || pass.length>=32 ) 
        {
            document.getElementById('perr').innerHTML = "password error";
            r++;
        }  
        if(r==3)
        {
            window.location= "i.php";
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>*
```

In i.php page i used var_dump to see the datas whether it has been submitted or not. code of the i.php page:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But its showing arry(0) {}
looks like there nothing that has been submitted.

Comment: You are simply redirecting to `i.php`. A redirect results in a GET request, thus the `$_POST` will be empty (since it is not a POST).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're redirecting with javascript, and losing the entire form and it's data by doing so.

When the form is valid, submit it rather than redirecting

```
function perform() {
  var _name  = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var pass   = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var dept   = document.getElementById('department').value;
  var gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
  var valid  = true;


  if (_name.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = "name not found";
    valid = false;
  }
  if (pass.length <= 6 || pass.length >= 32) {
    document.getElementById('perr').innerHTML = "password error";
    valid = false;
  }
  if (valid) {
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
  }
}
```

Note that `name` is not a good name for variables or form elements, as it already exists in `window.name`, and that a submit button can not be named `submit` as it overwrites the named `form.submit()` function

Another option would be to just remove all the javascript, and use HTML5 validation instead.

Comment: @AHSANHABIB - that's because once again you've messed up with the names. Your submit button can ***not*** be named `submit`, give another name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<form action="i.php" method="post" onsubmit="perform();">
```

And in javascript make these changes:

```
if(r!=3) {
alert('please complete the form';
return false;
}
```

> Javascript doesn't send POST headers with window.location!

By using this code, you don't need to use a button, javascript perform() function runs when the submit button is clicked in the form.
If form values are entered truly, javascript perform() does not return and form submits; else, the function returns and prevents submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not submitting the form you are just going to a different page with javascript without passing along any variables. so instead of doing

window.location= "i.php";

you should submit the form like so

document.getElementById("formId").submit();

so you should give the form the id formId

Comment: Its not working. Its not going to the i.php page. that I declared in the action inside form tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are merely redirecting to the i.php page without posting any data. Replace this line in your JS:

```
window.location = "i.php";
```

with this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

This will find the form in your DOM and submit it along with the data that has been input, preserving the values for your action page.

You also need to rename your submit-button for this to work. Otherwise you will not be able to call the submit function on the form programmatically.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
```

should do the trick. However, I don't really see the point of the submit button in addition to your validation/submission button.

Full code sample of the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/dwu96jqw/1/

Comment: Its not working. Its not going to the i.php page. that I declared in the action inside form tag.

Comment: See my latest edit. Your submit button's name is blocking the submit function.

Answer (score -1):

by press btn you redirect only and your form dont submitted for transfer  via _POST
you should change your code :

```
<form action="i.php"  method="post" id ="form1">
```

and :

```
if(r==3)
    {
        form1.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

`window.location` will redirect you to the page, to preserve field values return it

```
    if(r==3)
    {
        return true;
    }
```